# Converting jQuery class adding to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, converters

So I have a double `for`  loop and with jQuery depending on what is the current array item that loops goes through, I add certain `div`'s

How can I convert this to pure JavaScript?

Here is the context:

```
for (var i = 0; i < level.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < level[i].length; j++) {

        var n = level[i][j];

        if (n === 1) {
            $("<div>", {
                "class": "block stone ypos-0 xpos-" + [j]
            }).appendTo("#game");

        }
    }
}
```

Now how do I convert this part:

```
$("<div>", {
    "class": "block stone ypos-0 xpos-" + [j]
}).appendTo("#game");
```

To pure javascript?

Here is what I've tried:

```
var blocks = document.createElement("div");
blocks.classList.add("block", "stone", "ypos-0", "xpos-" + [j]);
game.appendChild(blocks);
```

Can someone explain:

- What is wrong?
- If the `+ [j]` is working?
- What to do/what code would work?

thank you!

Comment: change `[j]` to just `j`. Provide a [mcve] also

Comment: it doesn't work, https://codepen.io/FlipFloop/pen/aBBYPz

Comment: The demo seems to work fine but is using jquery not the code you are asking about

Comment: what is the variable `game` in your example?

Comment: @charlietfl I want to create a jQuery - free code (to get used to pure JS)

Comment: @Dekel game is the div where everything goes, codepen.io/FlipFloop/pen/aBBYPz

Comment: So what isn't working with what is shown? Giving us a demo that doesn't use that code doesn't help much. Your example should contain the code that **isn't** working

Answer (score 2):

Your code for appending works, here's the [example](https://jsfiddle.net/stb1pk5x/). Problem (in your [codepen](https://codepen.io/FlipFloop/pen/aBBYPz)) is, you don't call `javascriptVersion()` function, so do it at the bottom of your js code.